# Disable WPF DataGrid Row editing

Tags: wpf

How do you disable row editing for DataGrid in WPF ? It seem i can't find a property for this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you take a look at DataGrid's [IsReadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.isreadonly.aspx) property?

From the link:

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the user can edit values
>   in the DataGrid.

Comment: oh man.. lol can't believe ive missed this. Ive looked for ReadOnly but not IsReadOnly.. Thanks.

Comment: Yup. It is a little bit of a curve ball. Especially since there are other Boolean properties that start with `CanUser`... but deal with adding and deleting rows but not editing.